# NotWritableException in Image.php line 143: Can't write image data to path (C:\Users\SurajLifeean\surj\public\images/)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and faced a problem while working on image  uploading. I am getting an error as

```
NotWritableException in Image.php line 143: Can't write image data to path (C:\Users\SurajLifeean\surj\public\images/)
```

This code is inside my controller.

```
  $image=$request->file('featured_image');
  $filename=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $location = public_path('images/',$filename);
  Image::make($image)->resize(800,400)->save($location);$post->image=$filename;
```

i have accross a solution to include at the begining

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

but it didnt help.
can any one suggest me a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your error message you got two issues,

1 ) `NotWritableException` means that your folder you are trying to touch is not writeable, which means that you need to give that folder 777 permissions

2 ) you are under windows environment, while you are using UNIX directory separator.

it's always good practice to use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant as directory separator instead of fixed separators.

as follows:

```
$location = public_path('images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $filename);
```

or simply in your case use :

```
$location = public_path('images\', $filename);
```

Comment: I did as suggested but the problem persists.

Comment: NotWritableException in Image.php line 143:
Can't write image data to path (C:\Users\SurajLifeean\surj\public\images\)

Comment: for the permission i need to get into images folder and then do chmod 777. right? @hassan

Comment: give the image folder itself 777 permissions

Comment: I've just also give the permission for it. and it worked .